# getting "TypeError: string indices must be integers error" while iterating dataframe in to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

below is the data frame df

```
country           value
NETHERLANDS      230.156
UNITED STATES    60.128544
India            25.12
```

getting issues while running the below code

```
data=[]
for i in df.iterrows():
    data.append({
       'c': i['country'],
       'v': i['value']
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iterrows` yields both the row index and the row, so you need to catch **both** in the loop:

```
data=[]
for index, row in df.iterrows():  ## here
    data.append({'c': row['country'],
                 'v': row['value'],
                })
```

output:

```
[{'c': 'NETHERLANDS', 'v': 230.156},
 {'c': 'UNITED STATES', 'v': 60.128544},
 {'c': 'India', 'v': 25.12}]
```

###### pandas alternative

It would however be easier to run:

```
data = df.rename(columns={'country': 'c', 'value': 'v'}).to_dict('records')
```